# how can i insert plain words into a open math equation?

Tags: openoffice

Question: How do i use keywords in open math equations as the words not the symbols they represent?

---

Info: I'm trying to write up a proof in open Math, it goes well until I try to say something like "Let A and B be sets" and end up with "Let A ^ B be sets" it sees the "and" and puts in the and symbol, but I want the word. So does anyone know how I can use keywords as plain words in open math?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use quotes together with the `ital` command:

```
Let A ital "and" B be sets
```

gives

[image]